# How can I understand the properties of a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable, dice

> Suppose that $F$ is the distribution function of a real-valued random variable $X$.
>
> 1. $F$ is increasing: if $x≤y$ then $F(x)≤F(y)$.
> 2. $F(x+)=F(x)$ for $x∈R$. Thus, $F$ is continuous from the right.
> 3. $F(x−)=P(X<x)$ for $x∈R$. Thus, $F$ has limits from the left.
> 4. $F(−∞)=0$.
> 5. $F(∞)=1$.

Let,

$Experiment$ = rolling a fair die.

So, $CDF = F(x) = \begin{cases}
               0,  & \text{if $0 \ge x$ or $6 < x$} \\
               x \cdot \Bbb P(X=x), & \text{otherwise}
           \end{cases}$
**(is it correct??)**

then, how can I explain the above properties?

Comment: (1) That's not the CDF for rolling a fair die. (2) What are you asking? Do you want to show that the CDF for rolling a fair die satisfies the above properties? (3) Is this a homework question? If so, you should tag it with [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @MatthewGunn, (1) Plz, help me to correct it. (2) I want to understand 1-5 using, if possible, a picture or a graph. (3) No. Self-study.

Comment: Are you comfortable, skilled with calculus?

Comment: Your CDF is incorrect, it should be $1\quad \text{if } 6<x$

Comment: @MatthewGunn, I am comfortable with calculus. Not skilled.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ here is a discrete random variable, so the CDF of a discrete random variable is a summation. In this case: $\Pr(X \leq x) = \sum_{i=1}^6 \Pr(i)\mathbb{1}_{(i \leq x)}$.

You would integrate over the pdf of $x$, as it looks like you were trying to do, only if $X$ was a continuous random variable.

The + and - notation in the excerpt that you've quoted above is only to give us a framework for discussing atoms, or discontinuities in the density.